# Why is this HTTP header not printed?

Tags: perl, network-programming, libpcap

I have the following code:

```
Net::Pcap::loop($pcap, -1, \&proccess_packets, '');
sub proccess_packets {
    my ($user_data, $header, $packet) = @_;
    my $ip_packet = NetPacket::Ethernet::strip($packet);
    my $tcp_packet = NetPacket::IP::strip($ip_packet);
    my $tcp_obj = NetPacket::TCP->decode($tcp_packet);
    if ($tcp_obj->{data}) {
        my $request = HTTP::Request->parse($tcp_obj->{data});
        my %headers = split /[:\n]/, $request->headers_as_string;
        print Dumper($headers{'Accept-Language'});    # this line is printed
        print $headers{'Accept-Language'};            # this line is not printed
    }
}
```

Could someone have any explanation why this line is printed:

```
print Dumper($headers{'Accept-Language'});
```

and why this is not printed:

```
print $headers{'Accept-Language'};
```

What could be the problem here? Could someone give an advice? Is it related to the callback mechanism of libpcap?

Comment: The code you have there will not compile for several reasons.  Please post the exact code that you are working with.

Comment: Hi Eric I understand you but the exact code is about 1K of lines ,I revisted this snippet of  code again hopes now it will be more clear .

Comment: [sample code](http://sscce.org) should be self-contained, complete yet concise, so that it's testable. You don't need to post the original, just fill out the sample to produce a minimal test case. The problem might have something to do with code not shown. If we have to add code to make the sample complete, it may not have the same behavior as the code you're testing. Also, what is the output you're seeing, and what is the output you're expecting?

Comment: And, of course, aside from making it easier for others to help you, creating runnable minimal test cases to demonstrate your problem also has the incredibly useful characteristic that, in the process of simplifying down to the minimal case, you'll often stumble across the solution on your own.

Answer (score 2):

I did not run your code, however to me the header handling with split looks wrong. Instead simply use the [`header`](http://p3rl.org/HTTP%3a%3aRequest#%24r-%3Eheader%28_%24field_%29) method that HTTP::Request inherits.